# x-client-transaction-id in twitter

Tags: javascript, python, twitter, request, header

I'm trying to get profile data from Twitter, but recently I noticed that in Twitter there is a parameter 'x-client-transaction-id' in the request headers, which is why my script is not working, does anyone have any idea how to get the value of the parameter 'x-client-transaction-id'
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I looked into the source and it seems like the parameter is generated here:

```
    function Nn(e) {
        return async(n,t)=>{
            if (!Bn.test(n.host))
                return t(n);
            const a = {
                ...n
            };
            if (e.isTrue("rweb_client_transaction_id_enabled")) {
                const {method: e, path: t} = n;
                try {
                    a.headers["X-Client-Transaction-Id"] = await async function(e, n) {
                        xn = xn || new Promise((e=>{
                            d.e("ondemand.s").then(d.bind(d, 71269)).then((n=>e(n.default())))
                        }
                        ));
                        const t = await xn;
                        return await t(e, n)
                    }(function(e) {
                        return (e || "").split("?")[0].trim()
                    }(t), e)
                } catch (e) {
                    a.headers["X-Client-Transaction-Id"] = btoa(`e:${e}`)
                }
            }
            return t(a)
        }
    }
```

From https://abs.twimg.com/responsive-web/client-web/main.bfe3e92a.js.

Maybe you can continue from there.